# Is "I'm on them" a valid phrase?

Tags: countability

When I'm working on some issue or bug, I say "I'm on it" to let others know that I'm working on it.

Can I say "I'm on them" if I'm working on multiple issues? Or do I still need to say "I'm on it" regardless of the number of the things I'm working on?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on multiple things you can simply say

> **I'm working on them.**
>   **I've got them covered.**

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely say "I'm on them." You can also say "I'm on it" referring to the general task of fixing those bugs, but there's nothing wrong with the plural construction.